# Create Freezable image from non-Freezable image

Tags: wpf

I have a DrawingImage that uses DynamicResources for its colors.  I want to then use that image in an animation, however you can't use objects that use DynamicResources in animations because they are not Freezable.  I know I can't have its colors dynamically change during the animation, I don't care about that.  I just want to create a version of this image which I can use in the animation.  So basically have the image evaluate all its resources, then spit out a version of it that I can call Freeze on to use in the animation.  Surely this must be possible?  I must be able to, for instance, write this image out to disk?  That must create a Freezable version of it, no?  I've googled and searched StackOverflow but can find nothing useful...  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try the `GetAsFrozen()` method?

Comment: Yes but that only works if the CanFreeze setting is true, which it's not due to the DynamicResources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was surprisingly difficult to dig up a solution to, but I seem to have found one.  I made this handy extension, which will take my DrawingImage and encode it as a PNG via the PngBitmapEncoder, then write that to a memory stream, then load that into a BitmapImage which is Freezable and can be used in my animation.  Whole lotta work for something so simple!

```
public static class DrawingExtensions
{
    public static BitmapImage GetAsFreezableBitmapImage(this DrawingImage drawingImage)
    {
        return drawingImage?.Drawing?.GetAsFreezableBitmapImage();
    }

    public static BitmapImage GetAsFreezableBitmapImage(this Drawing drawing)
    {
        if (drawing == null)
            return null;

        var drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();

        using (var drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen())
        {
            drawingContext.PushTransform(new TranslateTransform(-drawing.Bounds.X, -drawing.Bounds.Y));
            drawingContext.DrawDrawing(drawing);
        }

        var bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)drawing.Bounds.Width, (int)drawing.Bounds.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        bitmap.Render(drawingVisual);

        var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmap));

        var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            encoder.Save(stream);
            bitmapImage.BeginInit();
            bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            bitmapImage.StreamSource = stream;
            bitmapImage.DecodePixelHeight = bitmap.PixelHeight;
            bitmapImage.DecodePixelWidth = bitmap.PixelWidth;
            bitmapImage.EndInit();
        }

        return bitmapImage;
    }
}
```